# dart2native is not recognized

Tags: dart, dart2native

First I install the flutter that contains the dart-sdk at
`C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk` and I added this path to the environment variables
but I still get `'dart2native' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` after I ran `dart2native`

Then I install the dart-SDK by using the choco (follow docs) and adding this path to the environment variables. but I still get this error.
How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dart2native` command was removed in Dart 2.15.0 released 2021-12-08. From the changelog:

> Breaking change [#46100](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46100): The standalone `dart2native` tool has been removed as previously announced. Its replacements are the `dart compile exe` and `dart compile aot-snapshot` commands, which offer the same functionality.

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/2.15.0/CHANGELOG.md#dart-command-line

Comment: Thank you, I talk with chatGPT for a long time and tried to use dart2native T^T

Comment: ChatGPT stopped learning some time ago.  Not reliable for flutter, which changes so fast that even six months invalidates things.